# Apache TIKA - Add new metadata value

Tags: java, apache, metadata, apache-tika

I'm using Apache TIKA to add a new metadata value to .doc file.

```
File file=new File(filepath);
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
FileInputStream inputstream=new FileInputStream(file);
ParseContext context =new ParseContext();
parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, context);
metadata.add("Author","My Author");
```

If I list all metadata values of the document:

```
String[] metadataNamesafter = metadata.names();
for(String name : metadataNamesafter) {     
   System.out.println(name + ": " + metadata.get(name));
}
```

The Author was changed, but this property isn't saved in the physical file.
Someone could tell me what to do?

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you aware that Apache Tika is a library for extracting text and metadata, not changing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, Apache Tika doesn't support this. Currently (July 2015), Apache Tika only provides ways to *extract* Metadata and Textual content from files. As such, it isn't possible to have your changes saved into the file.

This is something that has been discussed in the Apache Tika community, and a proof-of-concept *Embedded* has been created, using external programs, aimed at image files. You can find the [interface here](http://tika.apache.org/1.9/api/org/apache/tika/embedder/Embedder.html) and the [implementation javadocs here](http://tika.apache.org/1.9/api/org/apache/tika/embedder/ExternalEmbedder.html). At some point, it's likely that most of the main formats will support Embedding changed metadata back into the formats, but that isn't possible today. Right now, the focus of the community is largely on extracting, not saving.

Comment: Thanks for the answer